# what is the equivalent for :"new" of pl sql in postgresql?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plpgsql

I used to use ":new" to get the last inserted row in oracle pl sql. But now i'm migrating the solution to postgresql. So what is the syntax which I can use for similar function.

Comment: Just `NEW` , without a colon

Comment: See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)